# Is there a way to make tag CSS3 work without DOCTYPE in SAP BSP?

Tags: html, css, doctype, sap-bsp

Is there a way to make tag CSS3 working without DOCTYPE? You may think, why the hell I do need this!

In BSP page, default tags (`html`,`title`) are provided by SAP, and we cannot change them. They do not include `DOCTYPE` and we cannot add `DOCTYPE` tag since there is a restriction of using this tag. Bur I must be able to use CSS3 in my BSP application. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _> we cannot add DOCTYPE tag since there is a restriction of using this tag_ ... Is the restriction somewhere publicly documented? The [answer by tomdemuyt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10032470/5846045) indicates that you can define your own `index.html`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not forced to use the standard SAP html tags, you can write your own.

This is perfectly valid BSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
<!-- CSS Files -->
<link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Scripts -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest doing anything you can to include a `DOCTYPE` in your markup.

If you really can't change the source code of the application you're working on, you might be able to prepend the `DOCTYPE` using your web server (for example, in IIS I believe you can add to outgoing responses), so that might be something to look into.

Answer (score 2):

If you **REALLY** cannot work out a way to get the `DOCTYPE` tag into the application, in order to get these effects working, subject to SAP restrictions, you will need to look at another solution such as the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com), [Wijmo](http://www.wijmo.com) or the [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com) libraries that use JS/jQuery.

The reason I raise these options even though JS/jQuery isn't tagged is simply they are all cross-platform and only require jQuery at the most. Where I enjoy building CSS3 apps for internal use where I know all browsers support what I'm writing, I find for "public" applications the library solutions are often better depending on your requirements.

Each library has it's own advantages depending on what you need, I would recommend searching for other CSS3 replacement libraries as well, these are just the 3 I happen to be using in my last few applications as they suited our needs.

Good luck!